# Getting String in ListView

Tags: android, listview

Ok, I have a ListView with two TextView per item view.

[image]

TextView unique_id holds the number 3 and 4 while TextView dateTime holds the date and time below the 3 and 4.

Now what I want to do is, example, I click the first item, I'll get the "3" string. Or if I select the second item, I'll get the "4" string. How can I do that?

**displayview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/unique_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTime" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, data, R.layout.displayview, new String[]{"unique_id","dateTime"}, new int[]{R.id.unique_id,R.id.dateTime});
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {

        // What will I put here to get those strings?
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
    TextView tv= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.unique_id);   // initialize
    String value = tv.getText().toString(); // get text from textview 
    }
    });
```

Edit:

You can also use

```
    String value = data.get(arg2).get("unique_id");
```

and you can avoid initializing textview as njzk2 posted.

Note: Using the second method is a better option as you won't be initializing view's.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't know I can use the view.findViewById.

Comment: don't get your values from the textView. Anything can have been done to this data, it totally depends on the getView in the adapter.

Comment: @njzk2 agree that's why i added your solution also in my post. I @ first din't realize he was using a list of hashmaps.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `data` List that contains your data. Like so:

```
 String value = data.get(arg2).get("unique_id");
```

It is always better that your controller gets the data from the Model, rather than from the View, as you may have adapted the content to make it look better in the view (truncate, round, add HTML parts...)

### Edit

Nota: The `arg2` param is the position in the list of the selected item.

Answer (score 1):

To help you understand the `onItemClick` method more clearly, lets change the variable names in a more understanding manner

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
TextView unique_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.unique_id);
String unique_id_Value = unique_id.getText().toString();
}
```

Comment: interesting to change the names of the variables but you are not using them, so i fail to see the point?

Comment: As mentioned earlier, it's only for more understanding manner. In future you could use the same for other logics as well (as in retrieving a value from a list that had been populated from a JSON webservice and loaded onto the listview etc.